# LambdaExpression DynamicInvoke throws 'Parameter count mismatch'

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, expression

I have a method ApplyExpression:

```
public object ApplyExpression (object value, LambdaExpression expression)
{ 
    object result = Expression.Lambda(expression).Compile().DynamicInvoke(value);
    return result;
}
```

And the call in first case:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var expression = Expression<Func<DateTime, DateTime>> expression = a => a.AddDays(1);
var date = ApplyExpression(dateTime, expression);
```

In this case value is type 'DateTime' and ExpressionBody is 'value.AddDays(1)'.
This should return InputDate + 1 day.
But it throws exception:'Parameter count mismatch'.
The second case is type 'string' and ExpressionBody 'value + "1"';

UPDATE Solved by @elgonzo:

```
expression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(value);
```

Comment: As the error says: "_Parameter count mismatch_"... Are you expecting us now to blind-guess how many parameters the lambda expression you passed to the ApplyExpression method really requires and what the type of those parameters would be?

Comment: Just the 2 cases in example.
I will add second example.

Comment: You could perhaps try `expression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(value);`...

Comment: That solved it, thx.